# How to have more than one Flip Card 3D only CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, flip

Hi I try to create 3D flip cards only via CSS / JS but I can't make it work properly. Firstly I don't know how to have more than one flip card without using different classes, then I don't really know how to change the on click zone, I prefer to add a link "+" and "-" instead of clicking everywhere. So Please can you tell me how:

- can I have more than one card?
- flip the card only when we click on +/- and not on the whole card ?
- have a variable height who depend on the content of the card

thank you

```js
$('.container').on('click', function () {
  $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
   }

body  {
  background: #00A5F7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
   }
   
   
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  border-radius: 4px;
   }  
 
.links {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
    } 

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
   }

  div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font: 16px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #47525D;
   }

  .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);   }

 .flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>



  <body>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
    <p class="links">+</p>
      There are many
    <div class="back">
      <p class="links">-</p>
     hello I'm here too.</div>
  </div>
  
</div>


  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: please add valid css

Comment: sorry I've updated it